Segmentation fault when using printf to print a float in x86-64 Assembly (AT&T syntax)
I'm trying to write a simple x86-64 assembly program (AT&T syntax) to calculate the sum of a float array and print the result using printf. Here’s my code:
asm
.section .data
msg: .asciz "Result is: %f\n"
n: .int 5
a: .float 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5
res: .float 0

.section .text
.globl main
main:
    xor %ecx, %ecx
    movss res, %xmm0
    mov n, %ebx
    
    while:
        cmp %ebx, %ecx
        je end_while
        
        addss a(,%ecx, 4) , %xmm0
        inc %ecx
        jmp while
        
    end_while:
    
    mov $msg, %rdi
    mov $0, %eax
    call printf
    
    call exit

Problem: When I run this program, I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I suspect there’s something wrong with how I’m using the printf function, but I’m not sure where the issue is.
Am I using the printf function correctly in this context?
Is there something wrong with the way I access the float array (addss a(,%ecx,4), %xmm0)?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

eax must be set to the number of floats you pass to printf.  Why do you set it to zero when you do in fact pass one float?  Also, what commands do you type to assemble and link this code?  Are there any warnings during linking?

Also you need to align the stack and better use 64 bit addressing (RIP-relative if possible) in 64 bit mode. Furthermore %f takes a double not a single precision float (should not cause a fault though).
